# Usage of "though" in formal writing

Tags: formality

Consider the following text: "It is a bicycle. How do we know it is a bicycle, though?". Would this be a reasonable use of *though* in formal writing (in an essay)?

What are the ways of avoiding this construction if one would want alternatives (except for skipping the *though*)? Would *however*, for example, work? The question doesn't really contradict what is stated, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"However" [functions](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv136.shtml) as a more formal version of adverbial "though", this mainly due to an informal appeal to the reader that "though" suggests when it comes at the end of a sentence. On a different note, it doesn't always imply a direct contradiction. It could simply imply a qualification or contrast to what has already been stated.

For example, you could use it to qualify something to avoid confusion.

> "I'm sick. I still would like to meet for coffee, though".

On the contrary, you could use it to contradict a previous statement.

> "My boss told me not to come to work because I was sick. I had too much work to do to stay home, though".

In your example,

> "How do we know it is a bicycle, though?"

might not (we'd need more context) contradict whether it is a bicycle or imply any contrast, but rather seek to qualify its bicycle-ness.

If you were compelled to change the wording, here are three options that incrementally emphasize the qualification:

> "It is a bicycle, **but** how do we know it is a bicycle?"
>
> "It is a bicycle, **yet** how do we know it is a bicycle?"
>
> "It is a bicycle; **however**, how do we know that it is a bicycle?"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you clarify your position on the use of "though" in formal writing, though? Avoid it as a general rule?

Comment: @citizen: I don't think it's really a matter of avoiding *though* as such. The thing is you're using it to ask a chatty/informal rhetorical question - which is all very well if you're a lecturer trying to engage your audience (in *speech*), but it's not exactly the done thing in "formal writing". Where the tendency is to avoid referring directly or indirectly to the *reader* (by asking him a question) just as much as it is to avoid referring to the *writer* (formal writing usually avoids **I**).

Comment: @citizen: I clarified where I could, but part of the issue is not with the word "though" but with it's placement at the end of a sentence where it creates an informal appeal to the reader.